# How to customise Django's default email template? (smtpd)

Tags: python, django

How to customise Django's default email template?

urls.py

```
path('change-password/', views.change_password, name='change-password'),
path('reset-password/', PasswordResetView.as_view(template_name='accounts/reset_password.html'),
     name='reset-password'),
path('reset-password/done/', PasswordResetDoneView.as_view(), name='password_reset_done'),
path('reset-password/confirm/<uidb64>/<token>/',
     PasswordResetConfirmView.as_view(), name='password_reset_confirm'),
path('reset-password/complete/', PasswordResetCompleteView.as_view(), name='password_reset_complete'),
```

I was hoping to customise the django email template and put it as a template_name or similar in one of the correct paths above? Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

In order to change the email default template, you'll need to:

- Point the template dirs' search directive to your application first, then to Django's default templates if you haven't done:

```py
   TEMPLATES = [
       {
           'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
           'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates')],
           'APP_DIRS': True,
           ...
       },
   ]
```

- Make sure that you're editing the right template. It's the [password_reset_email.html](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/contrib/admin/templates/registration/password_reset_email.html), you should create a template directory within your application called "registration", and then customize it the way for your likes. But don't forget to use the required fields such as URL token for validation in password reset.

So the directory and the structure should be *app_dir/templates/registration/password_reset_email.html*.